# AZURE endpoints have stopped working

Tags: azure, azure-networking

For virtual machines configured in my subscription since 14/06/2017, an endpoint configured for an application that requires a TCP communication port in the 1025-32000 range is no longer working.
Until the above date, the application worked regularly for several months.
At the time of service interruption I detected in the virtual machine with Windows 2012 r2 in the Event Log System the following event: ID: 43 'Installation started. Windows has started the installation of the following update: Definition Update for Microsoft Endpoint Protection - KB2461484 (Definition 1.245.890.0) '
I tried uninstalling the malware protection service, disabling the firewall, but without solving the problem.
I then tested the problem by installing two other virtual machines with Windows 2008R2 and 2016 but the problem is equally present.
Interrogating ports configured through portqry are listening but the application does not receive TCP traffic
I believe that some new service has been activated from the above date on the AZURE platform that filters the traffic generated by the application. The same application installed on our servers with the same OS it works regularly.

Comment: Have you contacted Azure support?

Comment: For test. try to edit NSG to none, maybe NSG block your ports.